# How do I know the "From" of an email? (Using IMAP)

Tags: python, imap

In this case I am downloading plain text from an email with a criteria,
but how do I know the @gmail.com adress who sent it. 
I am using Python 3.5.4

```
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
#imaplib module implements connection based on IMAPv4 protocol
mail.login('myemail', 'mypassword')


mail.list() # Lists all labels in GMail
mail.select('inbox') # Connected to inbox.


result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(HEADER Subject "[News]")')
#search and return uids instead
i = len(data[0].split()) # data[0] is a space separate string
for x in range(i):
   latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x] # unique ids wrt label selected
   result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
   # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
   raw_email = email_data[0][1]

 #From = email.utils.parseaddr(email_data['From'])
 #continue inside the same for loop as above
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
# converts byte literal to string removing b''
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
#this will loop through all the available multiparts in mail
for part in email_message.walk():
 if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain": # ignore attachments/html
     enter code here`body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
     save_string = str("Llave de amigo" + str(x) + str("a"))
     # location on disk
     myfile = open(save_string, 'a')
     myfile.write(body.decode('utf-8'))
     # body is again a byte literal
     myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not obvious from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) (assuming Python 2.7), but the email_message object acts like a `dict`, by implementing the `__getitem__` function.  Since you fetched and parsed the entirety of the message, you should be able to access it simply as:

```
email_message['from']
```

Note, this gives you a raw representation of the header, which is probably okay in a lot of cases.

You may then want to use [`email.utils.parseaddr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html?highlight=parseaddr#email.utils.parseaddr) to break it into constituent parts:

```
realname, addr = email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['from')).
```

`email.utils.getaddresses` might be useful if you then parse To or Cc headers with more than one recipient.

If you need to deal with internationalized headers in older versions of Python, `email.header.decode_header` and [`email.header.make_header`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html#email.header.make_header) can be used.

In Python3.6, this has changed [significantly](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage), and should be more straightforward.